# Having a lot of trouble writing variable data into a database, no tracebacks but it still wont write in the db

Tags: python, sqlite

I cant figure out how to write data to a db because it wont traceback or anything. my project involves me taking a bunch of ticker symbols and running it through a REST api, pulling out the values from the json, then sorting it to a database. I am able to get all the variables but im having a lot of trouble writing the variable values into the db at all. Here is an example of the variables i get from the program, and the failed write to the db. im a newb so pls explain like im 5 :)

```
import sqlite3
o=1
l=2
h=3
c=4
t='amd'
data=[t,o,l,c,h]
conn=sqlite3.connect('volindex1.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stonks''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Stonks(ticker TEXT,low INTEGER, high INTEGER, open INTEGER, close INTEGER)''')
c.executemany('INSERT INTO Stonks VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',(data,))
```

Comment: Are you calling `conn.commit()` after making these updates?

Comment: yep, forgot to add it here but i think its  a syntax error in the sql or something, or I need to brush up on tuples but something is not allowing me to log the variables inside the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, need to convert the variable name `c` for `conn.cursor()` to another one such as `cur`. Since `c` is also represent a counterpart for the column `close` of the table in your current case.

Then, you can nest those variables with square brackets one more time such as

```
data=[[t,o,l,c,h]]
```

and then call execution as

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO Stonks VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',data)
```

presuming `Stonks` table is composed of those five column only. Otherwise, of course you need to list those five columns individually within this INSERT statement such as

```
INSERT INTO Stonks(ticker,low,high,open,close) VALUES...
```

*Of course, don't forget to add*

```
conn.commit()
```

*after issuing the DML statement.*